# JPA using variable Schema name in annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, database-schema

I'm using the Java Persistence API to describe tables from my database that i will manipulate in my code.

However, the **schema** used is not be the same depending on where my project will be installed. So, when I use the annotations, I would like that the SCHEMA field was a variable, but I can't make it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME", schema = schemaVariable, catalog = "")
```

How can I achieve that?
Is it possible with the **persistence.xml** file?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You can only use compile-time constants (which are all primitives and `String`) in annotations.

You can use final variables:

```
public class DatabaseMetadata {
    public static final SCHEMA = "MySchema";
}
```

and then use it in annotation:

```
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME", schema = DatabaseMetadata.SCHEMA, catalog = "")
```

but I think it's not what you wanted.

PS. On the other hand, there can be find examples of using i.e. Spring EL in annotations (see `@Value` annotation), but this requires *custom annotation processor*. AFAIK none of `JPA` providers gives you such ablility.

Answer (score 0):

Putting schema information (like table, column, schema names) in java classes is a bad idea any time IMHO (forcing recompile if you want to deploy elsewhere). You could put that info in `orm.xml` and just deploy a different `orm.xml` dependent on your deployment requirement.

As for `persistence.xml` you would be dependent on your JPA provider having a persistence property that defined the default schema/catalog. I know DataNucleus JPA (what I use) has this, but no idea for Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you would be using different schemas, I'd suggest to use 2 mapping files and define

```
<entity-mappings> 
    <persistence-unit-metadata> 
       <persistence-unit-defaults> 
          <schema>HR</schema> 
       </persistence-unit-defaults> 
    </persistence-unit-metadata> 
... 
</entity-mappings>
```

In this way you will be able to easily change schemas, without any changes in the application code.

Comment: in which file should I add this xml ? and how can I link it with my persistance.xml file ?

Comment: @SamyOmar You define it in the `orm.xml` file which should be in the same folder (META-INF) as your `persistence.xml`. If you want to use non default name, then you need to register it in the `persistence.xml` via `mapping-file` element. See [here](http://www.bigdev.org/2012/01/overwriting-jpa-annotations-with-orm-xml/) for more details.